# Uploading files to Amazon EC2 via FileZilla

Tags: amazon-ec2

I managed to connect to Amazon EC2 files directory using FileZilla SFTP, but I have to Putty SSH the following command in every connection to be able to transfer files.

```
chown -R ec2-user /var/www/html
```

What command should I give so that I don't have to repeat the process in every FileZilla connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log in via FileZilla using the same username. If you upload a file via ftp, the file owner is the user you're using to log in.

Comment: i'm logging in using ec2-user but it doesn't have the permission to upload files to the server. I give to give permission using the command above.

Comment: if you chown it to ec2-user, what chown it back?